# How can I derive this equation?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

This equation is from this [paper](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/5407/1/LIFieeetpam06.pdf) and I can't understand how the right-hand can be derived from the left-hand using Bayes' rule:
$$\frac{p(O_{fg} \mid I, I_t)}{p(O_{bg} \mid I, I_t)} = \frac{p(I \mid I_t, O_{fg}) p(O_{fg})}{p(I \mid I_t, O_{bg}) p(O_{bg})}$$

Answer (score 0):

From Bayes' rule:

\begin{align}
\frac{p(O_{fg} \mid I, I_t)}{p(O_{bg} \mid I, I_t)}&=\frac{p(I \mid O_{fg}, I_t)p(O_{fg} \mid I_t)}{p(I\mid I_t)} \frac{1}{\frac{p(I \mid O_{bg}, I_t) p(O_{bg} \mid I_t)}{p(I\mid I_t)}}\\
 &= \frac{p(I \mid O_{fg}, I_t)p(O_{fg}\mid I_t)}{p(I\mid I_t)} \frac{p(I\mid I_t)}{p(I \mid O_{bg}, I_t) p(O_{bg} \mid I_t)}\\
&= \frac{p(I \mid O_{fg}, I_t)p(O_{fg}\mid I_t)}{p(I \mid O_{bg}, I_t) p(O_{bg} \mid I_t)}
\end{align}
Now I am not too sure about this topic exactly, but I think that $O_{fg}$ and $O_{bg}$ are independent from $I_t$, in which case $p(O_{fg} \mid I_t)=p(O_{fg})$ and similarly for $p(O_{bg}\mid I_t)=p(O_{bg})$, hence we get
$$
\frac{p(O_{fg} \mid I, I_t)}{p(O_{bg} \mid I, I_t)}= \frac{p(I \mid O_{fg}, I_t)p(O_{fg})}{p(I \mid O_{bg}, I_t) p(O_{bg})}
$$
as wanted. But please correct me if I'm wrong.